# Extending base activity to other activities navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I was following the android navigation drawer guide and all went well until i tried to to create a navigation drawer base activity so I can extend that activity and use the menu in all activities. unfortunately my app keeps crashing.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is or can anyone please point me in the right direction?

This is my Base Activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer1);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is About.java that should extend BaseActivity:

```
public class About extends BaseActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView a_text1,a_text2,a_text3;
ImageView a_img1, a_img2,a_img3;
String about1 = "Svojim kapacitetima i sa zaposlenima Sajam je osposobljen da zainteresovanim poslovnim partnerima pruĹľi najraznovrsnije usluge.\nBeogradski sajam ima zatvoreni i otvoreni izloĹľbeni prostor. ÄŚetrnaest hala Beogradskog sajma poseduje 100.000 kvadratnih metara izloĹľbenog prostora. Centralna hala (Hala 1) je monumentalna graÄ‘evina sa kupolom, ukupne povrĹˇine 21.280m2. Svojom veliÄŤinomizdvajaju se joĹˇ Hala 2 (9.239m2), Hala 3 (4.438m2) i Hala 14 (11.665m2) izloĹľbene povrĹˇine.\nUkupna povrĹˇina otvorenog izloĹľbenog prostora je 35.363m2";
String about2 = "Beogradski sajam raspolaĹľe i poslovnim prostorom, magacinima i radionicama. Na Sajmu funkcioniĹˇu prateÄ‡i sadrĹľaji: poĹˇta, banka, turistiÄŤke agencije, Ĺˇpediterske sluĹľbe, carinska sluĹľba i ambulanta. TakoÄ‘e, u okviru Sajma rade i ugostiteljski objekti razliÄŤite namene.\n\nNa Beogradskom sajmu se odrĹľi godiĹˇnje viĹˇe od 30 redovnih meÄ‘unarodnih sajamskih manifestacija. Sajmovi se odlikuju visokim nivoom organizacije te su mnoge priredbe uÄŤlanjene u ugledne meÄ‘unarodne organizacije: MeÄ‘unarodni sajam tehnike i tehniÄŤkih dostignuÄ‡a, MeÄ‘unarodni sajam odevanja - Moda u svetu, MeÄ‘unarodni sajam nameĹˇtaja, opreme i unutraĹˇnje dekoracije i MeÄ‘unarodni sajam graÄ‘evinarstva ÄŤlanovi su MeÄ‘unarodne unije sajmova (UFI, Pariz).\n\nMeÄ‘unarodni salon automobila je jedan od zvaniÄŤnih registrovanih centara za izlaganje proizvoda automobilske industrije od strane Stalnog biroa proizvoÄ‘aÄŤa motornih vozila (OICA, Pariz).";
String about3 = "Pored redovnih manifestacija pod kupolama Beogradskog sajma odrĹľavaju se brojne izloĹľbe, koncerti, nauÄŤni i specijalizovani skupovi. Ukupna ponuda Beogradskog sajma dopunjuje se bazarom robe Ĺˇiroke potroĹˇnje. Na Beogradskom sajmu godiĹˇnje izlaĹľe oko 5000 kompanija, a obiÄ‘e ga preko 1.500.000 posetilaca. \n\nBeogradski sajam je od 2001. godine ÄŤlan i Centralnoevropske asocijacije sajmova (CEFA). \n\nOd septembra 2003. godine Medjunarodni sajam turizma ÄŤlan je Evropske asocijacije turistiÄŤkih poslovnih sajmova (ITTFA).\nOd 2004.godine Beogradski sajam je ÄŤlan Asocijacije sajmova JugoistoÄŤne Evrope (EASE).\nOd 1991. godine, Svetski trgovaÄŤki centar Beograd ÄŤlan je Asocijacije svetskih trgovaÄŤkih centara (WTCA) sa sediĹˇtem u Njujorku. Povezuje najznaÄŤajnije taÄŤke meÄ‘unarodne trgovine u najsavremeniji komunikacijski sistem i omoguÄ‡ava kontakte sa poslovnim ljudima i firmama iz viĹˇe od 330 gradova ÄŤlanica Asocijacije iz preko sto zemalja.\n\nBeogradski sajam je osnivaÄŤ Svetskog trgovaÄŤkog centra Beograd (1991.)";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer);
    FrameLayout placeHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about, placeHolder);

    a_text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a_text1);
    a_text1.setText(about1);

    a_text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a_text2);
    a_text2.setText(about2);

    a_text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a_text3);
    a_text3.setText(about3);

}
```

}

This is my nav_drawer.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer1"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

logcat

```
05-07 21:34:58.106: I/ActivityManager(290): START u0 {cmp=com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.About} from pid 800
05-07 21:34:58.126: W/WindowManager(290): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
05-07 21:34:58.268: D/AndroidRuntime(800): Shutting down VM
05-07 21:34:58.286: W/dalvikvm(800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:48)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.About.onCreate(About.java:23)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  ... 11 more
05-07 21:34:58.616: W/ActivityManager(290):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.About
05-07 21:34:58.646: W/ActivityManager(290):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.MainActivity
05-07 21:34:59.156: W/ActivityManager(290): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40efad28 u0 com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.About}
05-07 21:34:59.486: I/Choreographer(290): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-07 21:34:59.536: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-07 21:34:59.546: I/Choreographer(412): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-07 21:34:59.978: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-07 21:35:12.816: W/ActivityManager(290): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40f16b00 u0 com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.MainActivity}
05-07 21:35:12.836: W/ActivityManager(290): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40efad28 u0 com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/.About}
```

If there is something Obvious that I am missing please tell me because I am pretty new to app developing community.

Any help is greatly Appreciated.

Thank You! :)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 21:34:58.456: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:48)  -- Where's line 48?

Comment: In BaseActivity line 48 is:  mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

Comment: Do i have to change that line? thank you

Answer (score 1):

There should be only one `DrawerLayout` per `Application`. The way it works is that you should replace `Fragments` depending on a selection on the drawer's list. `DrawerLayout` is intended as a centralized component to provide easy access to deep `View` hierarchies within your `Application`. For example, if it takes a user going through 3 screens to get to the "Profile" page you can provide a better experience if you add it as an item in the drawer.

Comment: I don't want to use activitys over fragments, I just want to use different activities which uses all the same navigation drawer. I want activity, because there I can use different types of layout, and also in the main window i have main menu, i would like to use that main menu for navigating through the app (for example when i click on fair info icon in main menu i would like to open new window which have the same nav drawer), and to use navigation drawer only for some options (like setting, preferences). I hope you understand me, sorry english is not my native language.. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise taking a different route than trying to create multiple activities that use the nav drawer. Android has available fragments which is the way android seems to be headed. So instead of using multiple activities, you should be using multiple fragments and switching out the fragments when needed.

This link is a good starter for getting the navigation drawer up and going. 
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

After that, you will just handle the drawers selection and replace out the fragment in the main activity with the next fragment.

You will use

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();
```

when you want to switch out fragments.